# Is there any website for ranking ubuntu softwares?

Tags: software-center

I using software.toptenreviews.com for windows softwares, But I don't know how can find best software for ubuntu.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: For me it would be the Ubuntu Software Center or [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)

Comment: Also check http://www.getdeb.net, Visit [top downloads](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/08/top-10-ubuntu-app-downloads-for-july/) & [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AccessoriesApplications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to ubuntu software center.Click on the particular software you want to install,you will see rating and user reviews there(Though the reviews are not available for all softwares there).